# Single software RAID partition missing after replacing failing HDD

Tags: software-raid, mdadm

I have a raid-1 with 5 partitions (md0 - md4). 
Last night one of the HDDs failed (the faulty RAID partition was md4), I removed it, replaced it with a new one and now in the rescue system suddenly md2 is gone (isn‘t listed in /dev/).

I already tried to rescan via mdadm --assemble --scan but without any luck.

What can I do to recover md2?

As requested, here the output of lsblk:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0      4G  1 loop
sda       8:0    0    2.7T  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0      1G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0 1023.4M  0 raid1
├─sda2    8:2    0    512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  511.7M  0 raid1
├─sda3    8:3    0    512G  0 part
├─sda4    8:4    0     50G  0 part
│ └─md3   9:3    0     50G  0 raid1
├─sda5    8:5    0    2.2T  0 part
│ └─md4   9:4    0    2.2T  0 raid1
└─sda6    8:6    0      1M  0 part
sdb       8:16   0    2.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0      1G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0 1023.4M  0 raid1
├─sdb2    8:18   0    512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0  511.7M  0 raid1
├─sdb3    8:19   0    512G  0 part
├─sdb4    8:20   0     50G  0 part
│ └─md3   9:3    0     50G  0 raid1
├─sdb5    8:21   0    2.2T  0 part
│ └─md4   9:4    0    2.2T  0 raid1
└─sdb6    8:22   0      1M  0 part
```

Comment: Please post the output of `lsblk`

Comment: @shodanshok Thanks for your help! I added the output of lsblk to the OP.

Comment: Ok, can you add the following output: `cat /proc/mdstat; mdadm -D /dev/md2; mdadm -E /dev/sda3; mdadm -E /dev/sdb3` ?